# javascript date manipulation weirdness

Tags: javascript

I want to create two dates that contain the beginning date of a month and the beginning date of the following month. This is what I have:

```
var TheMonth = "6.2012"; // as in june 2012
TheMonth = TheMonth.split(".")

var TheDisplayDate = new Date(parseInt(TheMonth[1], 10), (parseInt(TheMonth[0], 10) - 1), 1);

var TheUpperLimit = new Date(TheDisplayDate.getFullYear(), TheDisplayDate.getMonth(), 1);

//I'm adding a month here but it's not changing the month
TheUpperLimit.setMonth(TheUpperLimit.getUTCMonth() + 1);
```

The problem is that TheUpperLimit turns out to be the same date. I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KTXyC/) to look at.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `getUTCMonth` with `setMonth` instead of `setUTCMonth`. It's more correct to use only UTC or only non-UTC methods together. When you use `setMonth` and `getMonth`, it seems to work correct. But when you use UTC variations of these functions, it gives you 2 jul instead of 1 jul (in my time zone, at least). I suggest you to use the following code to avoid complications with time:

```
var TheMonth = "6.2012"; // as in june 2012
TheMonth = TheMonth.split(".");
var month = parseInt(TheMonth[0]);
var year = parseInt(TheMonth[1]);
var second_month = month + 1;
var second_year = year;
if (second_month > 12) {
    second_month = 1;
    second_year++;
}

var TheDisplayDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
var TheUpperLimit = new Date(second_year, second_month - 1, 1);
console.log([TheDisplayDate, TheUpperLimit]);
// => [Date {Fri Jun 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSK)}, 
//     Date {Sun Jul 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSK)}]
```

Comment: ok, this is a different way of solving the same problem. I figured out  my problem: getUTCMonth was actually choosing May 31 because of timezone changes and adding a month to May was displaying June again. Your solution avoids this problem; thanks.

Comment: No. When `TheMonth = "12.2012"`, `month = 12` and `second_month = month + 1 = 13`. Condition `second_month > 12` will be satisfied only in 12th month.

Answer (score 1):

According to your nick(`@frenchie`), your local time is probably French time. This means `GMT + 2:00`.

When you are setting for example:

```
new Date(2012,5,1)
```

it means you have:

```
year=2012, month=June, day=1, hours=minutes=seconds=mseconds=0
```

As `GMT + 2:00`, `UTC Date` will have `-2` hours offset. If you would do `TheUpperLimit.toString()`, you will see, that you have `Thu, 31 May 2012 22:00:00 GMT`. This means, your `UTC Month` is '4'.  So when you are adding '+1' you will have '5' for month and it was June.So there is nothing wierd.

Comment: yeah, I figured it out; see the comment above. I decided to go with the proposed solution to avoid this timezone problem.

Comment: @frenchie I did not notice your comment, when I was writing my answer. :)